# Azure Data Factory - converting lookup result array

Tags: arrays, azure-data-factory

I'm pretty new to Acure Data Factory - ADF and have stumbled into somthing I would have solved with a couple lines of code.

**Background**

Main flow:

1. Lookup Activity fetchin an array of ID's to process
2. ForEach Activity looping over input array and uisng a Copy Activity pulling data from a REST API storing it into a database

**Step #1** would result in an array containing ID's

```
{
    "count": 10000,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "799128160"
        },
        {
            "id": "817379102"
        },
        {
            "id": "859061172"
        },
        ... many more...
```

**Step #2** When the lookup returns a lot of ID's - individual REST calls takes a lot of time. The REST API supports batching ID's using a comma spearated input.

**The question**
How can I convert the array from the input into a new array with comma separated fields? This will reduce the number of Activities and reduce the time to run.

Expecting something like this;

```
{
    "count": 1000,
    "value": [
        {
            "ids": "799128160,817379102,859061172,...."
        },
        {
            "ids": "n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,...."
        }
        ... many more...
```

**EDIT 1 - 19th Des 22**
Using "Until Activity" and keeping track of posistions, I managed to use plain ADF. Would be nice if this could have been done using some simple array manipulation in a code snippet.
[image]

Comment: what is your source for getting array of Ids?

Comment: In this case it is a SQL Server providing a result set with the IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal response might be we have to do manipulation with Dataflow -

**My sample input:**

[image]

1. First, I took a Dataflow In that adding a key Generate (Surrogate key) after the source - Say new key field is 'SrcKey'

[image]

Data preview of **Surrogate key 1**

[image]

2. Add an aggregate where you group by `mod(SrcKey/3)`. This will group similar remainders into the same bucket.

[image]

3. Add a collect column in the same aggregator to collect into an array with expression `trim(toString(collect(id)),'[]')`.

[image]

Data preview of **Aggregate 1**

[image]

Store output in single file in blob storage.

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive solution. I'm marking it as a solution. I was hoping that this could be done using "plain" ADF - and I managed to do so (see update).

Comment: Another important aspect in my case is that I need to limit the size of the commaseparated Strings to a fixed number - not only partitioning it.